# How can I get an answer on my question deleted, when my flags are denied?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have this answer to my question: [Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387120/253772), but it doesn't answer my question at all. I have flagged it as not an answer (disputed), once as requesting moderator intervention (denied), and again, with a more detailed explanation, requesting moderator intervention (TBD).

As this question has been up for quiet a while, and there is currently a 500 rep bounty on it, I don't want people to not answer it solely because it already has an answer. As this does not answer my question, I request that it gets deleted.

Comment: If anything, the active bounty is going to make it a lot less likely that people will be deterred from answering by an existing answer. People generally understand that the manually rewarded nature of bounties makes it a lot more worthwhile to post the best answer possible even if there are already other answers.

Comment: Additionally (at time of writing), the current answer has -4 votes. Large bounties tend to attract low quality answers like this, so you shouldn't have to worry that much of other users not answering because there is another answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first flag was declined by the community, and your second flagged was declined by a moderator. The reason your flag was declined is because the "Not an Answer" flag isn't intended for wrong answers, it's intended for posts that don't even attempt to answer the question:

> **Not an answer**
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Primarily this flag is intended for posts such as "Thanks!" and "I'm having the same problem", neither of which attempt to answer the question. A post which actually attempts to answer the question, but is just wrong, should just be downvoted instead of flagged. One of the standard flag decline messages moderators can use actually says this too:

> Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So in this case, the system is working as intended.

As for your concerns around the answer deterring other users,  I wouldn't worry about that at all. What murgatroid99 and Wondercricket said is spot on: With a 500 rep bounty, users are going to click through to your question anyway. In fact, that incorrect answer would've actually bumped your answer back to the top of the front page too, so it probably helped draw more attention to it.

**Stealth edit:** Something else to keep in mind is that keeping the answer there makes it clear to other users the proposed solution won't actually work. If we deleted it, then another user might just come along and post the exact same thing.